# Searching a column in another column of another file in linux

Tags: linux, string, search, awk, grep

I have a multi-column files as following:

```
file1.txt
1 12 220 AJ-lett-K-MD
2 33 312 BCJ-23-660-numm
4 22 55  lett-C-100b
5 52 59  lett-C-100bc
6 82 995 numm-X-aab
```

And,

```
file2.txt

1 338 339 89839,lett;847447,AJ-lett-K-MD
2 223 443 numm;33920;numm3,AJ-lett-K-MD,50
3 443 223 AFFVlett-C-100b,lett-C-100b
4 542 442 187;lett-C-100bc
7 765 765 XXXX-CCC
```

I am trying to search the `4th` column of `file1.txt` in `4th` column of `file2.txt`, and if it exists, then printing the `1st,2nd,3rd` columns of `file1.txt` with the `4th` column of `file2.txt`, on top of the contents of `file2.txt`.

For example, `4th` column of `1st line` in `file1.txt` is **AJ-lett-K-MD**. It exists in `4th` columns of `1st and 2nd lines` in `file2.txt`.

So, I need to print the `1st,2nd and 3rd colums` of `1st line` of `file1.txt` with `4th columns` of `1st and 2nd lines` of `file2.txt` :

So the expected output should be:

```
expected.txt
1 338 339  89839,lett;847447,AJ-lett-K-MD --> original
1 12  220  89839,lett;847447,AJ-lett-K-MD --> combination of file1 and file2
2 223 443  numm;33920;numm3,AJ-lett-K-MD,50 --> original
1 12  220  numm;33920;numm3,AJ-lett-K-MD,50 --> combination of file1 and file2
3 443 223  AFFVlett-C-100b,lett-C-100b --> original
4 22  55   AFFVlett-C-100b,lett-C-100b --> combination
4 542 442  187;lett-C-100bc --> original
4 22  55   187;lett-C-100bc --> combination
5 52  59   187;lett-C-100bc --> combination
7 765 765 XXXX-CCC
```

My trial is to get the words of `file1.txt` as variables,and then search it in `file2.txt`:

```
grep -v ^# file1.txt | while read a b c d; do echo a=$a b=$b c=$c d=$d;
grep "$d" file2.txt
```

It gives:

```
1 338 339 89839,lett;847447,AJ-lett-K-MD
2 223 443 numm;33920;numm3,AJ-lett-K-MD,50
3 443 223 AFFVlett-C-100b,lett-C-100b
4 542 442 187;lett-C-100bc
```

But then, I do not know how to proceed. Would it be better to use `awk` or `python`? Any help is appreciated!

PS : The `4th` column in `file1.txt` is not unique, and I need all matches (not only the first one).

IMPORTANT EDIT :  I have explained my question in a different and better way in : [Searching partial match of string in a column in a column of another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49255099/searching-partial-match-of-string-in-a-column-in-a-column-of-another-file)
They search for similar but different outputs.

Comment: Note, this item `lett-C-100b` occurs in both `3 443 223 AFFVlett-C-100b,lett-C-100b` and `4 542 442 187;lett-C-100bc`. Matching rules should be eloborated

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this case, it will map to this too. I am editing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching partial match of string in a column in a column of another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49255099/searching-partial-match-of-string-in-a-column-in-a-column-of-another-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

assuming file1 keys are unique and the first match is needed

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$4]=$1 FS $2 FS $3; next}
              {for(k in a) 
                 if("," $4 "," ~ "(,|;)" k "(,|;)") 
                    {print; print a[k],$4; break}}' file1 file2
```

if you need all matches remove the `break`.

If the keys are not unique this approach will only get you the last instance of the key value from the first file.  The following code will handle non-unique keys and multiple matches

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[++c[$4],$4]=$1 FS $2 FS $3; next}
              {for(k in c)
                 if("," $4 "," ~ "(,|;)" k "(,|;)") 
                   for(j=1;j<=c[k];j++) print $0 ORS a[j,k],$4}' file1 file2
```

Comment: plus 1, but I'd use `$4 ~ "\\\\<" k "\\\\>"` with word boundaries

Comment: I see, but only `;` and `,` seem to be used as delimiters.  For example `-` is part of the token and shouldn't be considered as word boundary.

Comment: I should add to my post, as the keys are not unique..and I need all matches

Comment: I have tried to add iteration with `awk -F '\t' '$1 == 1 {print $0}' file1.txt | while read line; do` but it only gets the last match

Comment: @karakfa Thank you. Can you please explain the line of `if` condition? Why does it begin with `","`?

Comment: we're wrapping both the literal and the line with delimiters to eliminate any false matches.  That is to force the regex always to match the full word instead of a sub string.  To do that you need at least a delimiter, I guessed you have two in that case `[;,]`, either would do.

Comment: @karakfa, yes sure. But can I also begin the `if` condition with `$4` without starting with `","`?

Comment: No! since on the right side of the regex it's expecting a delimiter.

Comment: But why cant it be a tab?

Comment: It can be any char that doesn't appear in the context.  Here you're using `[;,]` as delimiters in the composite key `$4`.  You can add tab, however need to change the right hand side as well.  To convince yourself just try with some simple input files.